# Modx Rev - Manager not showing all documents in list

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I have worked with ModX for a while, but can't seem to sort this issue. When I login as the admin in to the manager, the resources list is incomplete with not all documents displaying. I can however locate the files via the 'search' area just above.

I have done the normal, empty cache, flush permissions etc. without any joy. Interesting enough its always the same files, and they are showing in the front end.

Any help welcome on this one!

---

Update

---

When I click the blog (which is an articles resource) only the template variables panel is showing, nothing else. Page looks a little broken...

---

Update 2

---

If i remove the blog, (articles) the pages show. And... If I move the articles container higher, all resources show.

Comment: The only thing I can come up with that would explain that behavior is some sort of hierarchical loop, where the parent of the document you are looking for has a parent that no longer exists.. open the document for editing and on the Settings tab look at the "Parent" field - does that show an actual document or a non-existant ID?

Comment: Hi Mark, the document is in the root, and it's not only one but a few. In a couple of cases the document is a container and all is missing including the contents.

Comment: Have you done anything with resource groups / ACLs?

Comment: Nope. But... I had to uninstall 'articles' and for a min or two some had turned up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using multiple contexts? I've noticed this behaviour a few times when drag and dropping folders with nested resources from one context to folder in another context. 
Moving them back to the original context made them re-appear.

If you're familiar with MySQL GUIs like phpMyAdmin you could check and search the *modx_site_content* table and maybe correct the value in the resources' *parent* field manually. As Mark said it might well be a parent gone MIA.

Comment: No contexts, I have also checked MySQL row: modx_site_content) and no difference between the pages showing and the ones hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, parents rarely go MIA and by that I mean once every couple years....

Did you set up ACLs or Resource Groups?

Is your manager user a member of those groups?